# How to call external javascript function to ClientSideEvents.Click event?

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I have DevExpress().Button on a website which should take specific grid value from a focused row and pass it to external function.

Here is my button:

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(
             settings =>
             {
                 settings.Name = "btnMyName";
                 settings.Width = 120;
                 settings.Height = 25;
                 settings.Text = "MyText";
                 settings.Styles.Native = true;
                 settings.ClientEnabled = true;
                 settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { gridView.GetRowValues(gridView.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'MyValue', OnGetRowValues); }";
}).GetHtml()
```

I simply can't reach OnGetRowValues function - always get the same exception:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: OnGetRowValues is not defined

I have the script in the same folder as my .cshtml file and tried to reference it with `<script src=""></script>` in relative and absolute way. I tried to put the code to function directly between script tags to the cshtml page but nothing works and I get always the same error. The only solution which so far worked was to put the entire script as assingment to ClientSideEvents.Click but because the OnGetRowValues function is big, it will become messy and downright unpractical solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go through [Client-Side Events](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9448) documentation and implement using below example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ButtonClick(s,e)
    {
        gridView.GetRowValues(gridView.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'ShipName', OnGetRowValues);
    }
</script>
@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "btnGetSelectedRowValue";
    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "ButtonClick";
}).GetHtml()


@Html.Action("GridViewPartial")
```

index.js

```
// Value contains the "EmployeeID" field value returned from the server, not the list of values 
function OnGetRowValues(Value) {
    // Right code 
    alert(Value);
    // This code will cause an error 
    // alert(Value[0]); 
}
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice. Unfortunately it didn't help, turned out my code was fine but what was missing was tag `id="dxss_myCode"` in html page or `id="dxis_myCode"` for external javascript in `<script>` tag.

Comment: If you add that external javascript file in head section and then you can try to call implement as i shown in example.. I have done this lots of time in webforms application where i need to access devexpress control in external javascript. but remember to take care about the scope in javascript..

Comment: I didn't have devexpress control in external file. It was in .cshtml page and only the javascript function for click execution was in external file. I don't know why it didn't work without id.

Comment: yes.. they reside on the aspx page but can be accessed with ClientInstanceName of the control.. check the client library documentation of these controls.